# How do I fix broken apt-listchanges on Debian-RaspberryPi3?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I got this Error while trying the normal `sudo apt-get install update` and ...upgrade commands. Seems my pip package is broken at the apt-listchanges level. I tried uninstalling an reinstalling apt-listchanges but I still hit this error. Part of it is in german, but I hope the problem is understandable.

````
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
apt-listchanges ist schon die neueste Version (3.10).
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  attr coinor-libipopt1v5 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libmumps-seq-4.10.0 libraw15 python-dnspython samba-dsdb-modules
  samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools update-inetd
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 17 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Unterprozess /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 hat Fehlercode zurückgegeben (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10```
````

Answer (score 1):

Remove the package:

sudo apt purge apt-listchanges

or download an reinstall the package with sudo dpkg -i apt-listchanges*.deb

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't still work. I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This question probably belonged on [super user](https://superuser.com/), but it looks like your `apt-listchanges` package is broken and missing the actual program. A workaround would be to remove `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`, which tells `apt` to run it, and then you could reinstall the `apt-listchanges` package if you wish. Running `dpkg --purge apt-listchanges` should perform this change. In my humble opinion, it is a bug in the `apt-listchanges` package that removing it without purging leaves `apt` misconfigured.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic qiestione.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Is there a way to completely uninstall apt without using 'apt' in the command? I think that's the problem

Comment: I literally listed two ways that didn't use the `apt` command.